# How do I combine functions for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my input `id='currency'`

First I want [maskMoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/blob/master/jquery.maskMoney.js) for currency format

```
$(function () {
    $("#currency").maskMoney();
})
```

Then auto submit

```
$('#currency').change(function () {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

How to make it work together?

**Update : Code**

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://padmin.googlecode.com/svn-history/r21/trunk/scripts/jquery.maskMoney.0.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#currency").change(function() {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        }).maskMoney();
    });
    </script>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="currency" id="currency" />
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly do u mean by "How to make it work together?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be separate (as long as the first is in a `document.ready` handler) or combined in a chain, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#currency").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }).maskMoney();
});
```

Comment: @Blur - That shouldn't be the case, something funky with the plugin...do you have an example page I can see demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @Blur - what you have works great here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bwh4K/ ...what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @Blur - ...what alert? and which browser?

Comment: @Nick - `alert("submitting!")` no action on this one. I tried Firefox & Chrome

Comment: @Blur - you're clicking off the field to trigger the `change` event, right? it only fires on `blur`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#currency').change(function () {
    $(this).maskMoney();
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: This won't have the same effect...it won't apply the mask *until* a change happens :)

Comment: is this what is desired? 1. Mask should be applied as the typing happens and 2. the form be submitted on change?

Comment: @Omkar - `change` doesn't fire as the typing happens, it happens on blur...you're doing both on blur...the mask is to tell people what input is valid in that field, why would you apply it *after* they already entered something, given it's a template? :)

Comment: @Nick - you r right, it will happen on blur. to achieve as we type keyup has to be used.

Comment: @Omkar - again...why re-run a plugin every keypress that's made to be run once? :)